# Changing button state

Tags: python, tkinter, state

I want to change a button state to normal when all entry fields get filled. Please suggest me way to do it. When comment_name and comment_email are entered then button state change to normal. And, when they are empty then it's state will be disabled. Can we do it by adding one more function?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
 
 
class Feedback:
 
    def __init__(self, mainframe):
        mainframe.title('Add Your Comment')
        mainframe.resizable(False, False)
        mainframe.configure(background='#f7f7f7')
 
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure('TFrame', background='#f7f7f7')
        self.style.configure('TButton', background='#e1d8b9')
        self.style.configure('TLabel', background='#f7f7f7', font=('Arial', 12))
        self.style.configure('Header.TLabel', font=('Arial', 18, 'bold'))
 
        self.header_frame = ttk.Frame(mainframe)
        self.header_frame.pack()
 
        self.logo = PhotoImage(file='python_logo.gif')
        ttk.Label(self.header_frame, image=self.logo).grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)
        ttk.Label(self.header_frame, text='Comment App', style='Header.TLabel').grid(row=0, column=1)
        ttk.Label(self.header_frame, wraplength=300,
                  text=(
                      'Add your name, email, and comment, then click submit to add your comment.  Click clear if you make a mistake.')).grid(
            row=1, column=1)
 
        self.content_in_frame = ttk.Frame(mainframe)
        self.content_in_frame.pack()
 
        ttk.Label(self.content_in_frame, text='Name:').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, sticky='sw')
        ttk.Label(self.content_in_frame, text='Email:').grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, sticky='sw')
        ttk.Label(self.content_in_frame, text='Comments:').grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, sticky='sw')
 
        self.comment_name = ttk.Entry(self.content_in_frame, width=24, font=('Arial', 10))
        self.comment_email = ttk.Entry(self.content_in_frame, width=24, font=('Arial', 10))
        self.comments = Text(self.content_in_frame, width=50, height=10, font=('Arial', 10))
 
        self.comment_name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)
        self.comment_email.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
        self.comments.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5)
 
        ttk.Button(self.content_in_frame, text='Submit',
                   command=self.submit).grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='e')
        ttk.Button(self.content_in_frame, text='Clear',
                   command=self.clear).grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')
 
    def submit(self):
        print(f'Name: {self.comment_name.get()}')
        print(f'Email: {self.comment_email.get()}')
        print(f'Comments: {self.comments.get(1.0, "end")}')
        self.clear()
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Comment info', message='Thanks for your comment!')
 
    def clear(self):
        self.comment_name.delete(0, 'end')
        self.comment_email.delete(0, 'end')
        self.comments.delete(1.0, 'end')
 
 
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('500x400')
    feedback = Feedback(root)
    root.mainloop()
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the button in the beginning and then use `Entry.bind('<Key>', fun)` check whether there is an entry. If there is entry bring it back to normal state otherwise back to disabled state.

here is your code with that implemented

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
 
 
class Feedback:
 
    def __init__(self, mainframe):
        mainframe.title('Add Your Comment')
        mainframe.resizable(False, False)
        mainframe.configure(background='#f7f7f7')
 
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure('TFrame', background='#f7f7f7')
        self.style.configure('TButton', background='#e1d8b9')
        self.style.configure('TLabel', background='#f7f7f7', font=('Arial', 12))
        self.style.configure('Header.TLabel', font=('Arial', 18, 'bold'))
 
        self.header_frame = ttk.Frame(mainframe)
        self.header_frame.pack()
 
        #self.logo = PhotoImage(file='')
        #ttk.Label(self.header_frame, image=self.logo).grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)
        ttk.Label(self.header_frame, text='Comment App', style='Header.TLabel').grid(row=0, column=1)
        ttk.Label(self.header_frame, wraplength=300,
                  text=(
                      'Add your name, email, and comment, then click submit to add your comment.  Click clear if you make a mistake.')).grid(
            row=1, column=1)
 
        self.content_in_frame = ttk.Frame(mainframe)
        self.content_in_frame.pack()
 
        ttk.Label(self.content_in_frame, text='Name:').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, sticky='sw')
        ttk.Label(self.content_in_frame, text='Email:').grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, sticky='sw')
        ttk.Label(self.content_in_frame, text='Comments:').grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, sticky='sw')
 
        self.comment_name = ttk.Entry(self.content_in_frame, width=24, font=('Arial', 10))
        self.comment_email = ttk.Entry(self.content_in_frame, width=24, font=('Arial', 10))
        self.comments = Text(self.content_in_frame, width=50, height=10, font=('Arial', 10))

        self.comment_name.bind('<Key>', self.state_change)
        self.comment_email.bind('<Key>', self.state_change)
         
        self.comment_name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)
        self.comment_email.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
        self.comments.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5)
 
        self.submit = ttk.Button(self.content_in_frame, text='Submit',
                   command=self.submit)
        self.submit.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='e')
        self.submit['state']='disable'

        ttk.Button(self.content_in_frame, text='Clear',
                   command=self.clear).grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')

    def state_change(self, event=None):

        if self.comment_name.get() != '' and self.comment_email.get() != '':
            self.submit['state'] = 'normal'

        else:
            self.submit['state'] = 'disable'
         
    def submit(self):
        print(f'Name: {self.comment_name.get()}')
        print(f'Email: {self.comment_email.get()}')
        print(f'Comments: {self.comments.get(1.0, "end")}')
        self.clear()
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Comment info', message='Thanks for your comment!')
 
    def clear(self):
        self.comment_name.delete(0, 'end')
        self.comment_email.delete(0, 'end')
        self.comments.delete(1.0, 'end')
        self.state_change()
 
 
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('500x400')
    feedback = Feedback(root)
    root.mainloop()
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

**Update:**

since using the above method the state doesn't change after selecting the text and deleting them. Assign the text in the entry to a variable and use the `trace_add()` to connect to a function and then change the state.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
 
 
class Feedback:
 
    def __init__(self, mainframe):
        mainframe.title('Add Your Comment')
        mainframe.resizable(False, False)
        mainframe.configure(background='#f7f7f7')

        self.name = StringVar()
        self.email = StringVar()

        
        self.name.trace_add('write', self.state_change)
        self.email.trace_add('write', self.state_change)
 
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure('TFrame', background='#f7f7f7')
        self.style.configure('TButton', background='#e1d8b9')
        self.style.configure('TLabel', background='#f7f7f7', font=('Arial', 12))
        self.style.configure('Header.TLabel', font=('Arial', 18, 'bold'))
 
        self.header_frame = ttk.Frame(mainframe)
        self.header_frame.pack()
 
        #self.logo = PhotoImage(file='')
        #ttk.Label(self.header_frame, image=self.logo).grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)
        ttk.Label(self.header_frame, text='Comment App', style='Header.TLabel').grid(row=0, column=1)
        ttk.Label(self.header_frame, wraplength=300,
                  text=(
                      'Add your name, email, and comment, then click submit to add your comment.  Click clear if you make a mistake.')).grid(
            row=1, column=1)
 
        self.content_in_frame = ttk.Frame(mainframe)
        self.content_in_frame.pack()
 
        ttk.Label(self.content_in_frame, text='Name:').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, sticky='sw')
        ttk.Label(self.content_in_frame, text='Email:').grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, sticky='sw')
        ttk.Label(self.content_in_frame, text='Comments:').grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, sticky='sw')
 
        self.comment_name = ttk.Entry(self.content_in_frame, textvariable=self.name, width=24, font=('Arial', 10))
        self.comment_email = ttk.Entry(self.content_in_frame, textvariable=self.email, width=24, font=('Arial', 10))
        self.comments = Text(self.content_in_frame, width=50, height=10, font=('Arial', 10))

        #self.comment_name.bind('<Key>', self.state_change)
        #self.comment_email.bind('<Key>', self.state_change)
         
        self.comment_name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)
        self.comment_email.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
        self.comments.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5)
 
        self.submit = ttk.Button(self.content_in_frame, text='Submit',
                   command=self.submit)
        self.submit.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='e')
        self.submit['state']='disable'

        ttk.Button(self.content_in_frame, text='Clear',
                   command=self.clear).grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='w')

    def state_change(self, event=None, *args):
        if self.name.get() != '' and self.email.get() != '':
            self.submit['state'] = 'normal'

        else:
            self.submit['state'] = 'disable'
         
    def submit(self):

        print(f'Name: {self.comment_name.get()}')
        print(f'Email: {self.comment_email.get()}')
        print(f'Comments: {self.comments.get(1.0, "end")}')
        self.clear()
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Comment info', message='Thanks for your comment!')
 
    def clear(self):
        self.comment_name.delete(0, 'end')
        self.comment_email.delete(0, 'end')
        self.comments.delete(1.0, 'end')
        self.state_change()
 
 
def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('500x400')
    feedback = Feedback(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I have spotted an issue, if you enter something in the email field and the backspace it, the button still remains active, as your code requires a key to be pressed in order for the changes to take place, if don't perform an additional key press after deleting the contents the button will not be affected.

Comment: @AST ya you are right I have made an update